# Upload file with java servlet results in resource not found

Tags: java, forms, servlets, file-upload

I have a source I think should work but for some reason it gives me resource not found and a completely different resource.

HTML part, just simple form:

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Uploader</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        File:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Java part:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

 @WebServlet(name = "FileUploader", urlPatterns = "upload")
 @MultipartConfig
 public class FileUploader extends HttpServlet {

 private final static String serverPath = "/fileuploads";

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

OutputStream out = null;
InputStream filecontent = null;
final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

try {
  out = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverPath + File.separator + fileName));
  filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

  int read = 0;
  final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

  while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
  }
  writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + serverPath);

} catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
  writer.println("Missing file or no insufficient permissions.");
  writer.println(" ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());
} finally {
  if (out != null) {
    out.close();
  }
  if (filecontent != null) {
    filecontent.close();
  }
  if (writer != null) {
    writer.close();
  }
}
}

private String getFileName(Part filePart) {
String header = filePart.getHeader("content-disposition");
String name = header.substring(header.indexOf("filename=\"")+10);
return name.substring(0, name.indexOf("\""));
}
}
```

I would expect the file to be uploaded to /proj/publ/fileuploads but insted it tells me that the resource /proj/publ/uploads is not available....

The files are in /proj/publ/ folder. Why is it always pointing to that folder that does not exist?

Thank you for your help.

Viking

EDIT: Prob is solved... for some reason I created the java file in src and not in WEB-INF/src... so there was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource is not available because the servlet is not mapped to any URL pattern. This can be done either by XML declaration in /WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml or by [@WebServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#urlPatterns()) annotation.

I see that you already use @WebServlet so you have to add [urlPatterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#urlPatterns()) element. Something like this:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "upload", name="FileUploader")
```

Another thing to solve is the form's action attribute. Based on the servlet container and its configuration the resource won't be available at the root of the container. It usually is in the form of *host:port/application-context/url-pattern* however this is not a strict rule. To avoid constant changes what is the right URL you can use [JSTL's url tag](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm). Something like this:

```
form method="POST" action="<c:url ='/upload' />" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: Even after adding the urlPattern it still gives me the same error message. The second option with the c:url does not work either. It seems that the browser tries to access the folder via the url not the handler

Comment: message /proj/%3Cc:url%20=%20'/upload'/%3E is the message on the second version with The requested resource is not available

Comment: Does the request get to the server? If yes I guess you can then debug what the problem is. However if the request does not get to the server you should expect why - for example you can open browser's dev tools and see the network communication.

Answer (score 0):

basically resource not found is when the file we are trying to request is not found or the path of resource is not there.

> In your case please declare urlPattern in the webServlet annotation like this.

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/upload")

@WebServlet[https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html]

Comment: I did that but it doesn't change the problem:
 /proj/upload The requested resource is not available POST: http://localhost:8080/proj/upload ... and yes upload does not exist but it is surposed to use the html and java stated above and just upload the file.

Comment: now check the code make sure you have written like this /upload